# How can I apply dart extension methods in the Flutter Logging library?

Tags: flutter, dart, logging

I am trying [logging](https://pub.dev/packages/logging) library in my flutter project. They have some good record messages (e.g. record.name, record.message, etc.) For my project, I want to extend by using dart [extension methods](https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods) this package to add some more record message (e.g. record.version, record.eventName, etc.). As a beginner in dart, I am not sure completely how to do that?

Here is an example that I tried but failed.

```
extension CustomLog on LogRecord {
  String version(LogRecord version) => "1.0";
  String eventName(LogRecord eventName) => "userNameChangedEvent";
}
```

Please provide me some suggestions/examples how can I extend any package and use it on my own.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extend a class in Dart/Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56879606/how-to-extend-a-class-in-dart-flutter)

Comment: this is useful: https://dart.dev/guides/language/extension-methods

Comment: @tomerpacific not properly, but it gives me some ideas. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logging does not support extending (with extension) the LogRecord to add custom fields.

You can pass all your custom info as an class object in `object` param and retrieve it later.

Something like

```
class CustomLogAttributes {
    final String version;
    final String eventName;
    CustomLogAttributes(this.version, this.eventName);
}
```

then

log.fine("example log message", object: CustomLogAttributes("1.1.0", "example_event");